# Accurate String approximation in Python Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm trying to learn spark. I have two RDDs which have the following format:

```
RDD1
[["James Dean,1"], ["Roger Moore,2"]]

RDD2
[["22,1931,James Deen"], ["23,1927,Roger Moor"]]
```

Now the data in RDD2 might not be spelt correctly. I want to go through RDD1, check each name, then look up all similar strings in RDD2 and correct their spelling. How would I go about this? 
I'm new to Spark so I'm completely lost.

Comment: Look up edit distance. Try solving this in Python (or Scala) first before trying with Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Collect rdd2 at the driver & broadcast it back. Note that, if your rdd2 doesnt fit the driver's allocated memory, you will have OOM errors. Since you mentioned, this is a learning exercise, I guess, your rdds are not too big.

```
bc_var = rdd2.collect()  
v = sc.broadcast(bc_var)  

def fix_spelling(row):  
    name, id = row  
    for day, year, old_name in v.value:  
        new_name = compare(name, old_name) # compare name with old_name & determine if old_name needs to be fixed. 
    yield [day, year, new_name, old_name, name]  

rdd.flatMap(fix_spelling)
```